# Remove en from a URL with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have this page structure, for a multi-language website:

```
- Home En (/en)
   - Page1 En (/en/page1)
   - Page2 En (/en/page2)

- Home Es (/es)
   - Page1 Es (/es/page1)
   - Page2 Es (/es/page2)
```

The default language is `en`, I'd like to hide the `en` from the URL with a `htaccess` rule.

This is what is currently in my `htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/perch
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* /perch/core/runway/start.php [L]
```

I've tried adding this `RewriteRule ^/en/(.+)$ /$1 [QSA]` to the second line, but it has no affect.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/en/(.+)$ /$1 [QSA] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/perch
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* /perch/core/runway/start.php [L]
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it this way in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/en/(\S+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(?!en/). en%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/perch [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /perch/core/runway/start.php [L]
```

Comment: Hi @anubhava, thank you so much for taking the time to reply to this post. That does what I asked, however there must be an issue with the CMS I'm using as it says the page doesn't exist when I use that htaccess. This gives me a great starting point though. Thanks again.